# AzureWebJobsDashboard no longer supported, but added automatically to Azure Function App

Tags: terraform, azure-functions

In our Application Insights logs for Azure Functions there are a lot of warnings with the message:

> The Dashboard setting is no longer supported. See https://aka.ms/functions-dashboard for details.

We build our Azure resources using Terraform, and since our Function Apps target the "~4" runtime version we don't add the `AzureWebJobsDashboard` setting to our Function's Application settings. (According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsdashboard): The `AzureWebJobsDashboard` setting is only valid for apps that target version 1.x of the Azure Functions runtime.)

I was therefore surprised to find the `AzureWebJobsDashboard` setting with a value in the Azure portal. Any idea how it got there?

I deleted the setting manually in the portal for four of the apps we have running, and the logged warnings went away - however, the setting reappeared in one of them after a little while  Is there any way to make sure the deletion is permanent?

**Edit:** I tried deleting the setting manually for four new apps - making sure to save the changes, and the setting reappeared in two of them after some hours.

**Edit2:** After 1-2 days the setting is back in all eight apps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a special setting `builtin_logging_enabled` in terraform resource for Azure functions:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app#enable_builtin_logging

Setting it to false should disable `AzureWebJobsDashboard`.

Just add it in your azurerm_windows_function_app resource like this:

```
resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "func" {
  name = "sample-function-app"
  builtin_logging_enabled = false
  ...
}
```

Comment: For those searching for it, this also works for `azurerm_linux_function_app` and `azurerm_linux_function_app_slot`.

Answer (score 1):

***We have tried the same in our environment to check ,when deploying azure function using terraform if `AzureWebJobsDashboard` is there or not.***
[image]

***Yes,*** *It was there and the document you followed which is correct , So to it manually we need to follow the below to resolve the above issue*.

[image]

*To do that make sure that we have applied the* **`APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY`** after deleting **`AzureWebJobsDashboard`**
*And ***enabled App insights for our function app*** as shown below and the value will be store automatically after enable*.
[image]
[image]

*In your case, the configuration is appeared automatically after sometime or days, But if we  enabled the aforementioned it seems to be work*. *As we checked several times but still its not appeared.*

**NOTE:-** *we used Python3.9 with function runtime v4 in Linux environment*.

Below is the terraform code that we used for reproducing;

**`main.tf`**

```
provider "azurerm" {

features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "ajayXXXX"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "exatst"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "example-service-plan1"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "S1"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "example" {
  name                = "funterraform"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.example.id

  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key

  site_config {
    application_stack {
      python_version = "3.9"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_function_app_function" "example" {
  name            = "example-function-app-function"
  function_app_id = azurerm_linux_function_app.example.id
  language        = "Python"
  test_data = jsonencode({
    "name" = "Azure"
  })
  config_json = jsonencode({
    "bindings" = [
      {
        "authLevel" = "function"
        "direction" = "in"
        "methods" = [
          "get",
          "post",
        ]
        "name" = "req"
        "type" = "httpTrigger"
      },
      {
        "direction" = "out"
        "name"      = "$return"
        "type"      = "http"
      },
    ]
  })
}
```

*Source Code taken from* : **HashiCrop Terraformregistry**|[***azurerm_function_app_function***](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app_function)

*For more information please refer the below links:-*

- **GitHub Issue**| [***Remove support for AzureWebJobsDashboard***](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1923)
- **MICROSOFT DOCUMENT**| [***App settings reference for Azure Functions***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings).